# Best way to make scroll into a element

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I create scroll into a element, for do this I tried:

```js
 .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden;
 }
    
.scrollabe {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid style="height:100%" *ngIf="plat && ticket">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4 padding>
        <ticket-info [ticket]="ticket"></ticket-info>        
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="scrollabe" col-8 no-margin>
          <ticket-acao [ticket]="ticket"></ticket-acao>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

But this hides my content:
[My element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFbPT.png)

Also, i tried this way:

```js
.scroll-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <ion-content>
  <ion-grid *ngIf="plat && ticket">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4 padding>
        <ticket-info [ticket]="ticket"></ticket-info>        
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-8 no-margin>
        <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="height: 100%;width: 100%">
          <ticket-acao [ticket]="ticket"></ticket-acao>
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and the same issue occurs...

The problem is solved if i decrease the height, but i lose the responsive layout.

So, what is the best way to make that?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `style="height: 100%"` and both CSS rules you declared in there. The `ion-content` component will do the scroll for you if `ion-grid` overflows.

Comment: My purpose is create a scroll inside the element. Your solution works but it makes the entire page scrollable, not only that element...